# Image pdfmake customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, pdfmake

I'm using pdfmake and I have a image in base64 like this in the documentation.

How can I put the image before the title? 
[image: check photo]

```
extend: 'pdfHtml5',
orientation: 'landscape',
pageSize: 'A3',
sTitle: "id",
mDataProp: "id",
sWidth: '250%',[enter image description here][1]
customize: function(doc) {
doc.content.splice(1, 0, {
                  columns: [{
                        margin: 10,
                        alignment: 'left',
                        image: 'data:image/png;base64,/...',
                                    width: 95,
                                    height: 40,
                                },]
                            });
                        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`doc.content.splice(1, 0, {`

to be:

```
doc.content.splice(0, 0, {
```